# Display image gallery if more than 1 image

Tags: posts, images, gallery

I'm using this code to display image gallery in posts:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery link="attachment" columns="3"]'); ?>
```

How to display image gallery ONLY if the post has more than 1 image attached and hide this code if the post has only 1 image?

Comment: I'm not sure you can easily. You want to make the decision [here in gallery_shortcode()](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.3.2/wp-includes/media.php#L1899), where it already rejects no images, but there's no obvious hook to use at that point or later to abort. You might have to copy this code into your own plugin to modify it and add extra logic.

Comment: (Obviously you could duplicate the attachments query from there and count them first, but it would be nicer to avoid that I'd think. Unless it's cached, so the repeated call is free, which it might well be?)

Comment: oh, I am not good in programming.